# Cannot find module './lib/iterate.js'

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

When I run:

```
appc setup
```

or

When I try to create a new project on Titanium IDE I get this error:

```
Cannot find module './lib/iterate.js'
```

Does anyone know where this library comes from or where should I place it to solve the problem?

Comment: do you have the right versions of nodejs, appcelerator studio, cli etc?

Comment: Node: v9.11.1
Axway Appcelerator Studio, build: 5.0.0.201712081732
appc --version 7.0.2

Answer (score 1):

You're using an unsupported version of node. You can look at in the documentation at the [compatibility matrix](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-src-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Node.js) what versions are supported.

Right now the maximum node version is 8.9.x